# Finding value of $x$ and$y$

Tags: geometry

[image]

Finding the value of $y$

$ {y\over 3.6} = {1.5\over 0.9}$

$ 0.9y = 3.6 * 1.5 $

$y = {3.6 * 1.5\over 0.9}$

$y = 6$

But my answer is wrong! Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term $0.9$ in your answer should be $1.5+0.9$.

$$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle ADE  $$

$$\frac{BC}{DE}=\frac{AB}{AD}$$

The **triangles** are similar. You should use sides of triangles not the trapezium.

Comment: Can you please explain why you added 1.5 at the bottom? It gave me the correct answer but I don't know why. How do I use 'sides of triangles' and what is the differenece from 'sides of trapezium'?

Comment: @garena Done...

Comment: that is what I did?

Comment: @garena You did $AB/BD$.